# domain is not resolvable - "None of your nameserver names contain glue or A records"

Tags: dns, web, vpn, nameservers

I have moved my sites to a VPN hosting and have changed the name servers of the domains to the new name server that was given to me when i bought the VPN.
I have 2 .COM domains that have been registered at Godaddy and works fine with the new name servers but i also have 3 .co.il domains that are registered with 2 other companies and that are not resolving for an unknown reason.
I get this error: http://leafdns.com/index.cgi?testid=A3CFD1DF

> ("None of your nameserver names contain glue or A records. This error is fatal. Your domain is not resolveable")

The nameservers are registered and are pointing to the right ip (i checked with the hosting support).

What can be the problem?

Thanks,

Raz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The servers for `.IL` say that `israwords.co.il` is handled by the servers `ns1.building-websites.org` and `ns2.building-websites.org`.

The servers for `.ORG` say that `building-websites.org` is handled by `ns7.hostnine.com`, `ns8.hostnine.com` and `ns9.hostnine.com`.

All three respond with `REFUSED` when asked about `building-websites.org`.

Which means that no IP addresses can be found for `ns1.building-websites.org` and `ns2.building-websites.org`.

Which means that we can't know where to send queries for `israwords.co.il`, so that domain can't be resolved.

It's not clear from your question which, if any, of these names you control (please be more detailed when you ask questions here in the future), but at least now you know what's going on.

Comment: i control ns1.building-websites.org and ns2.building-websites.org
how did you check the response?

and how can i fix this problem?

Comment: The delegation for `building-websites.org` is broken. Fix that, and if there are no more problems hiding out, things should improve. And I started by doing `dig soa +trace israwords.co.il`, following up with some more specific queries to individual servers.

Comment: i'm new to this, how do i fix the delegation?

Comment: That is unfortunately too large a question to answer here. I'm afraid you probably need a competent local person who can help you.